# $\mathrm{ord}_p(x)$ and convergence in $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

> Let $x=\frac{22}{7} \in \mathbb{Q}$.
>
> (a) Find $\mathrm{ord}_p(x)$ for all primes $p$.

$\mathrm{ord}_2(x)=1,\ \mathrm{ord}_{11}(x)=1,\ \mathrm{ord}_7(x)=-1$ and $\mathrm{ord}_p(x)=0$ for all other primes.

> (b) Determine $|x|_p=p^{-\mathrm{ord}_p(x)}$ for all primes $p$.

$|x|_2=\frac{1}{2}$, $|x|_{11}=\frac{1}{11}$, $|x|_7=7$ and $|x|_p=1$ for all other primes.

> (c) Hence determine for which primes $p$ the geometric series $1+x+x^2+\ldots$ converges in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and what is the sum when it converges.

I know a series with terms $\in \mathbb{Q}_p$ converges if and only if the terms tend to zero.

Comment: You don't even need to use the fact that the terms go to zero.  Tthe geometric series $1 + x + x^2 + \cdots$ converges if and only if $|x| < 1$.

Comment: @D_S which is of course equivalent to the terms going to zero!

Comment: So $p=2$ and $11$?

Comment: Exactly. And once you know it converges, the standard techniques for finding the limit of a geometric series apply.

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-\frac{22}{7}}$?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you know enough. You need to know, when $|x^n|_p\to 0$.
But
1. $|x^n|_p=|x|_p^n$
2. for $a\in \mathbb R_{>0}$ occurs $a^n\to 0\Leftrightarrow a<1$.
As a result, we have that it happens only for $p\in\{2, 11\}$.